# how to set the background color of a RichTextCtrl in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a chatbox and I'm trying to colour every message with a different colour

```
class ChatDisplayer(RichTextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    def addMessage(self, message, red, green, blue):
        font = Font(12, DEFAULT, NORMAL, NORMAL, False)
        text_attr = RichTextAttr()
        text_attr.SetTextColour(BLACK)
        text_attr.SetFont(font)
        bg_color = Colour(red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
        text_attr.SetBackgroundColour(bg_color)

        self.BeginStyle(text_attr)
        self.AppendText(message)
        self.EndStyle()
```

this does append the text but it does not change the colour of the text of the background colour.
I can find the SetBackgroundColor attribute in the source code but not in the doc.

The main class is complex but looks like this:

```
class ChatMessageGrid(FlexGridSizer):
    def __init__(self, panel):
        super().__init__(6, 2, 9, 25)
    
        chat_message_apikey_label = StaticText(panel, label="API key")
        chat_message_apikey_input = TextCtrl(panel)

        chat_displayer_label = StaticText(panel, label="Chat", pos=(1, 0))
        chat_displayer_input = ChatDisplayer(panel, ID_ANY, style=TE_MULTILINE|TE_READONLY)

        chat_message_system_label = StaticText(panel, label="System")
        chat_message_system_input = TextCtrl(panel)

        chat_message_label = StaticText(panel, label="your message")
        chat_message_text = TextCtrl(panel, style=TE_MULTILINE)
        chat_message_button = Button(panel, label="send")

        model_choice_label = StaticText(panel, label="model")
        model_choice_box = ComboBox(panel, value="bbb", choices=model_choices)

        self.AddMany(
        [
            chat_message_apikey_label,
            (chat_message_apikey_input, 1, EXPAND),
            chat_message_system_label,
            (chat_message_system_input, 1, EXPAND),
            (chat_displayer_label, 1, EXPAND),
            (chat_displayer_input, 1, EXPAND),
            (chat_message_label, EXPAND),
            (chat_message_text, 1, EXPAND),
            (model_choice_label, EXPAND),
            (model_choice_box, EXPAND),
            (chat_message_button, EXPAND),
            ]
        )

        self.AddGrowableRow(2, 1)
        self.AddGrowableRow(3, 1)
        self.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        chat_message_button.Bind(
            EVT_BUTTON,
            lambda event: self.onClick(
            event,
            chat_message_system_input,
            chat_message_apikey_input,
            chat_displayer_input,
            chat_message_text,
            model_choice_box,
            chat_message_button
            ),
        )
    
    def completeRequest(self, messages, model, apiKey, chat_displayer_input, message, 
    button):
        # call the service
        userMessage = "User:\n"
        aiMessage = "Assistant:\n"

        # update the UI
        CallAfter(chat_displayer_input.addMessage, userMessage, 176, 210,167)
        #CallAfter(chat_displayer_input.addMessage, aiMessage, 176, 210,167)

        # re enable the button
        button.Enable()

    def onClick(
        self,
        event,
        chat_message_system_input: TextCtrl,
        chat_message_apikey_input: TextCtrl,
        chat_message_historic_input: ChatDisplayer,
        chat_message_text: TextCtrl,
        model_choice_box: ComboBox,
        button: Button
    ):
        if not len(chat_message_apikey_input.GetValue().strip()):
            MessageBox("API key is empty!", "Error", OK | ICON_ERROR)
        elif not len(chat_message_text.GetValue().strip()):
            MessageBox("type something please!", "Error", OK | ICON_ERROR)
        else:
            apiKey = chat_message_apikey_input.GetValue().strip()
            message = chat_message_text.GetValue().strip()

        button.Disable()

        # create a thread to run the API call
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.completeRequest, args=(messages, 
        model_choice_box.GetValue(), apiKey, chat_message_historic_input, message, 
        button))
        t.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is because you are `appending` the text and it is using the attributes that are currently in force at that position.
Your options would be to change the attributes at the current position or insert the text with a `write` and new attributes.
e.g.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test RichTextCtrl')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text1 = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self.panel, value="Rolf is not a surfer,\nbut he likes to the beach", pos=(10,10), style =  wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.VSCROLL, size=(300, 90))
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Insert",pos=(10,110))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_Button)
        self.text1.Enable(False)
        self.Show()

    def On_Button(self, event):
        self.text1.SetInsertionPoint(34)
        text_attr = wx.richtext.RichTextAttr()
        text_attr.SetTextColour(wx.GREEN)
        bg_color = wx.Colour(red=255, green=0, blue=0)
        text_attr.SetBackgroundColour(bg_color)

        self.text1.BeginStyle(text_attr)
        self.text1.WriteText(" to go")
        self.text1.EndStyle()

        self.text1.SetInsertionPoint(-1)
        bg_color = wx.Colour(red=255, green=255, blue=0)
        text_attr.SetBackgroundColour(bg_color)
        text_attr.SetTextColour(wx.RED)
        self.text1.BeginStyle(text_attr)
        self.text1.WriteText(" on hot days")
        self.text1.EndStyle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I simply used the write method instead and it worked. Thank you